# Generating additional js file to be shared with Ember app

Tags: ember.js, babeljs, ember-cli

I would like my Ember app to generate an extra javascript file that can be consumed by non-ember apps, so the code can be shared without creating an extra project just for it.

Inside the app, I create a public folder with two files, index.js and notifications.js to test if the pipeline is working:

```
/app
  /public
     index.js
     notification.js
```

And the files:

```
//notification.js
export function test(){console.log('test')}

//index.js
import {test} from "./notifications";
```

window.console.log('loading...');
$(document).ready(function()  {
  window.console.log('initializing...');
  window.test = test;
});
Then in ember-cli-build file I create as a new output:

```
// ember-cli-build
app.import('app/public/index.js', { outputFile: 'assets/public.js' });
```

The transpiling seems to be working ok, but just creates a module out of index.js to be imported inside the app

```
 define('app/public/index', ['app/public/notifications'], function (_notifications) {
  'use strict';

  window.console.log('loading...');

  $(document).ready(function () {
    window.console.log('initializing...');
    window.test = test;
  });
});//# sourceMappingURL=public.map
```

How can I generate a lib that can be consumed directly in the browser?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear to me. Do you just want to include a javascript asset in your dist without modifying? Than easiest way is to put it into `public/assets`. If it's just about copying but you need more flexibility, you could use `broccoli-funnel`. If you like to "generate" something you need to be more precise of what should be done to get a good answer.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear, I want to take advantage of the Babel pipeline and use it to transpile X number of files to output a single one. Nothing related to the Ember app, but that can be consumed by the app and other applications / pages. Is it that more clear?